# Pentaho Kettle: Reading exchange rates

Tags: pentaho, transformation, kettle, spoon, currency-exchange-rates

I am a total newbie in Pentaho Kettle/Spoon.
I am reading a transaction table with amounts in different transaction currencies.
The requirement is to convert the amounts in standardized currencies(in this case, EUR and USD) using the live exchange rates.
What should be my approach? What are the steps of the transformation need to be considered?

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood you have a table with many different currencies and want to convert those to usd and eur right?
I think you will need a webservice or a table that delivers the current conversion rates for this

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some additional info on the table itself, which amounts to be converted to USD or EUR. Also what would be the final result you are expecting.

Please provide more info.

Comment: Sales Amounts are in different transaction currencies like INR, SAR, GBP, USD, EUR, etc. I want to standardize this by converting to 2 reporting currencies i.e. USD and EUR.